# combine two audio files with a command line tool

Tags: linux, audio, encoding, ffmpeg

I've to merge two (or more) audio files (like a guitar and a drum track) into a single file.
I'm running over linux CentOS and I'd need a command line tool to do so, because I've got to run this as part of a background process, triggered via crontab of a custom bash script.
I also need to be able to change the pan, volume, trim and start time (i.e I want the guitar track to start after 1.25ms after the drum track so that they can be both in sync with each other).

My first choice would be ffmpeg, but I was wondering if there could be something more specific, reliable and less fuzzy than ffmpeg.

thx a ton!
-k-

Comment: Hey, I'm wondering if you found something to suit what you're looking for (I'm looking for something similar). Or was sox good enough?

Comment: This question is answered in [How to overlay/downmix two audio files using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14528482/8776746).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for sure if sox can do all that (esp start time), but I think so: http://sox.sourceforge.net/

Certainly it would be my "goto" tool for that, short of writing my own.

Answer (score 4):

[Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) is the best way to do this. Your command would be the following:

```
sox -M guitar.wav drum.wav final.wav
```